# Permission issue with emacs for non-root user (Ubuntu 11.10)

Tags: linux, emacs, sudo, file-permissions

### Background

I'm working on my personal VPS configured mostly for learning sysadmin and personal projects.  Have run up against an issue where my non-root user could only create/edit files in emacs by using `sudo` command.  This is not an issue with directory permissions since I can create files with `touch` without sudo.

- Can't recall, but emacs may have been initially installed by the root user.
- User was created and added as follows:

  - `root@hadron:~# adduser my_user`
  - `root@hadron:~# addgroup admin`
  - `root@hadron:~# adduser my_user admin`

### Specifics

Running a command like `emacs newfile.txt` would always open a blank document that couldn't be saved, and noted the following in the file path at the bottom of the terminal: `File exists: /home/my_user/.emacs.d/`

Checking that .emacs.d file, the permission was as follows:

- `drwx------  3 root root      4096 2012-03-26 08:07 .emacs.d`

Changing the permission of the .emacs.d file to allow anyone to access it resolved the situation, but that doesn't seem like the proper solution:

- `chmod 777 ~/.emacs.d`
- `drwxrwxrwx  3 root root      4096 2012-03-26 08:07 .emacs.d`

What is the appropriate way of addressing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not completely clear which user tries to run the emacs.

Also it is unclear what the command

```
$ adduser my_user admin
```

does.  Do you mean

```
$ adduser --group admin my_user
```

here?

The directory `.emacs.d` in the user's home should be owned by the user himself. So a

```
$ chown -R my_user ~/.emacs.d
$ # Fix the 'broken' permissions
$ chmod go-w ~/.emacs.d
```

In the last command you might want to add also the `x` and `r` flag to remove read and execute permissions for group and other.

Comment: Grazie.  `chown -R` was what I was missing here.

Following up, `$ chmod go-w ~/.emacs.d` gives the following error on my system:
"chmod: cannot access \`go-w': No such file or directory"

But I've gone ahead with `chmod 700`, and confirmed all is working as expected.